# How to change port of Pentaho 5.1

Tags: pentaho

May I ask How to change port of Pentaho 5.1. I am using windows 10. Now the value is 8080 but I need to change, I have searched on the internet information, they asked me to modify some xml file, but the problem is, the files they mentioned does not exist in my Pentaho.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this official 5.1 [documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0P0/000/050),

Edit this `/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/conf/server.xml`.

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
    <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Then change the port number in `/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>fully-qualified-server-url</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:8080/pentaho/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Restart the BA server.

I have done this earlier and worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much